# Problems with Fortran-magic and other jupyter lab extensions

Tags: jupyter-lab, f2py, jupyter-extensions

I am originally a Fortran programmer, if anything. Last year I begun learning python and now I wanted to use fortranmagic to have a wrapper of f2py, but it is not working. Let me describe the steps I took and the resulting error messages, hoping for some help. I am working with Ubuntu 22.04

1. I begun by creating an environment `conda create -n lf` and activating the environment
2. I installed I few libraries I might need

   conda install numpy scipy matplotlib jupyter nodejs
3. Following the instructions of the Fortran-magic developer GitHub I run `pip install -U fortran-magic`

Everything installs fine, but when I create a notebook and execute

```
%load_ext fortranmagic
```

I get the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fortranmagic'`
4. I finally try to install the extensions from jupyter, as it is also suggested in the developer GitHub

```
%install_ext https://raw.github.com/mgaitan/fortran_magic/master/fortranmagic.py
```

Yet only to receive the following error `UsageError: Line magic function` %install_ext `not found.`

I hope you can help